# PHP code to create hyperlinks to the homepage?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a php site template and i want to create hyperlinks to the homepage on the internal pages. I tried this code which works in wordpress but doesn't work on my template: `<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">anchor text</a>`

What alternative code i can use to replace `<?php echo home_url(); ?>`, so it will work on my php template?

edit:
This worked `<a href="/">Homepage!</a>` but i have another problem. In my php template the most recent pages are displayed on the homepage in a same way as a wordpress site. For the inner pages I am using this code `<a href=" "> page title</a>` to create hyperlinks for the page title similiar to the blog posts in wordpress. The problem is that the pages on the homepage are linking to the homepage not to the page url. For exmple, page with title Blue Widget has this page url domain.com/blue-widget, but when the page is displayed on the home page the page title is linking to domain.com.

How can i make the page title that are displayed on the homepage to link to they corresponding page url and not to the homepage. The same way blog posts that are dispalayed on the homepage of wordpress site are linking to they blog post pages.

Comment: Is your site running on wordpress by any chance?

Comment: No, it is not wordpress site, just php template.

Comment: Then you cant use any functions that wordpress uses. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a constant, somewhere in a central place like a config file. Then use it throughout the script.

```
define ('SITELINK', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

And in your template:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITELINK; ?>">Go to home!</a>
```

Or you can wrap it into a function:

```
<?php
    function home_url(){
       return SITELINK;
    }
?>
 <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Go to home!</a>

 <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/about">Go to about page!</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Homepage link is just (when you have one domain):

```
<a href="/">Homepage!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

For referring only homepage:

In php

```
echo '<a href="/">anchor text</a>';
```

In Html

```
  <a href="/">anchor text</a>
```

Use "/" to redirect to home page from any other page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` is it can be unreliable on some instances such as subdomains, etc...

Here is WordPress' Reference Manual: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/network_home_url

In WordPress you can use:

```
$url = network_home_url();
echo $url;
```

So for you example it would be:

```
<a href="<?php echo network_home_url(); ?>">anchor text</a>
```

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function home_url(){
    ?><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>">Go Home</a><?php
}
home_url();
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` to get the home URL

Comment: Wordpress provides better ways to do it. In particular, your suggestion will break on subdomains, in subfolders, or on non-standard ports.

Comment: Well, i don't think he is referring to is in word press

Answer (score -1):

```html
<a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: `SERVER_NAME` is not really reliable. Easiest is to just make a relative link to `/`